# How to implement a function to count/display nodes by level in C++

Tags: c++, binary-tree

I was given this assignment in an online book and I can't figure it out. I think I have to use some kind of BFS or DFS but I don't know how to go about it.

I've haven't tried a ton of things in fear of wasting too much time, but what I have tried was using an iteration starting at a node and using a ton of if statements in order to find the different values at the nodes I needed but it just did not work at all.

```
string CharacterAnalyzer::nodeCountByLevel(nodeptr_t const node) const {
    /* TODO (1):
     * Return a formatted string of the node count at each level. For example for the 
     * text "Hello all!" the string will be:
     * 
     * Each line is terminated with a newline.
     * 
     * Node count by level:
     *    Level 1: TN(1), LRN(2), LON(0), RON(0), LN(0)
     *    Level 2: TN(2), LRN(0), LON(1), RON(1), LN(0)
     *    Level 3: TN(2), LRN(0), LON(0), RON(0), LN(2)
     *
     * where 
     * TN - level node count
     * LRN - two child node count
     * LON - left only child count
     * RON - right only child count
     * LON - leaf node count
     */

}// end nodeCountByLevel()

////////////////////////
//The accompanying code in .h
////////////////////////

  bool hasTwoChildren(nodeptr_t const node) const    { return (node->left && node->right);   }// end hasTwoChildren()

  bool hasLeftChildOnly(nodeptr_t const node) const  { return (node->left && !node->right);  }// end hasLeftChildOnly()

  bool hasRightChildOnly(nodeptr_t const node) const { return (node->right && !node->left);  }// end hasRightChildOnly()

  bool isLeaf(nodeptr_t const node) const            { return (!node->left && !node->right); }// end isLeaf()
```

Comment: _"it just did not work at all"_ is a very vague problem description. Post a [mcve] reproducing your problem as required here please.

Comment: What I was trying to say was my solution made no sense in trying to solve the problem. So, I don't know how to start creating a solution

Comment: It's your task to create one, not to ask others to do that for you.

Comment: I was looking for guidance on where to start, but you are right. thanks

Comment: If you want to traverse level-by-level, that's a job for BFS. You might also want to use some special node to indicate the end of the current level. So there's your guidance on where to start: try BFS.

Comment: Thanks I'll look into BFS

Comment: @jharre.99 Mandatory read for you: https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems

Answer (score 2):

One way of implementing a DFS is with a recursive function such as the following

```
void depth_first_search(const nodeptr_t node)
{
    // Do something with node
    // ...
    if (node->left)
        depth_first_search(node->left);

    if (node->right)
        depth_first_search(node->right);
}
```

You can easily make this function aware of what depth it's at as follows

```
void depth_first_search(const nodeptr_t node, unsigned depth)
{
    // Do something with node and depth
    // ...

    if (node->left)
        depth_first_search(node->left, depth + 1);

    if (node->right)
        depth_first_search(node->right, depth + 1);
}
```

The "do something" in your case would be then to update some container (e.g. a `std::vector`) with the counts of the types of nodes it encountered at this depth. To do so you of course need to have this structure accessible from within the function. This could be accomplished by either

- Making the container (or a pointer or reference to it) a global variable
- Implementing `depth_first_search` in a class which has the container as a member
- Passing the container as an additional argument to `depth_first_search`

A variant on this last option is to use a "Visitor Pattern", like so

```
void depth_first_search(const nodeptr_t node, unsigned depth, Visitor& visitor)
{
    // Do something with node and depth
    // ...

    visitor.visit(node, depth);

    if (node->left)
        depth_first_search(node->left, depth + 1, visitor);

    if (node->right)
        depth_first_search(node->right, depth + 1, visitor);
}
```

Some class derived from `Visitor` now knows exactly what to do with the node and depth information (e.g. count them and store the results in a container). The advantage here is that if you need to do something different with your nodes next time, you just implement a new visitor.